# Upload images to temporary image folder

Tags: php

I have a hosted website and i want to upload my images to image directory and link the image to mysql database .

What i did:

Creating form as :

```
<form method=POST align=center enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=file name=image>
```

Php code :

```
$uploaddir = 'images/';
     // echo $uploaddir;
        $target = "$uploaddir".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
              echo $target;

        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $sql="insert into News2(image_News2) 
    values($image)";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    copy($_FILES['tmp_name']['name'],$target,true);
```

What this code actually do is only inserting the image into the database not copying the image into the images folder.

What i searched for and found :

You shouldn't specify a http:// URL as $uploaddir but a path relative to the path where the php script is running from.

So i what i really wanted to do is :

1- Copying the image into image folder directory on website.
2- Linking the copied image to the database.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions Of The folder you're attempting to upload to? Apache will need write access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the name ïmage"
not:

`copy($_FILES['tmp_name']['name'],$target,true);`

but:

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);`

And maybe you should try the move first, before inserting it in the database, should that action fail (or filesize = 0) etc.

do check on both the file actions and the db actions, should they fail: rollback

extra:

is only 1 column present in your database table?
is it wise to use the uploaded file's name? Duplicates can happen. 
I would after checking the file insert the original name into the database. Get the autoincrement id of that record. rename the file to ./1234.jpg

through the database you can then later use the original name. But this numbering might go too var for a simple application

Comment: Great it worked i can accept your code in 5 minutes..
But how do i store the image link in the database ?

Comment: No i have many columns as id_news auto increment,name_news,..etc

Comment: if you have more columns, then you should mention them, or the ones used, in the insert query. `INSERT INTO tabel (image_name, foo, bar) VALUES ($target, 'foo', 'bar');`  (apart from escaping the input to be sure no ' in the input can cause any harm

Answer (score 0):

as per your given data you must close Form tag then give form action ="" attribute to specify url . and if your oprating system is linux then check folder permission in set or not , also check your database table if field name is set unique or not ? 
then write below code in given url file

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code :

```
     if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] 
     == 0) {
     $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
     $temp_file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
     $name = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
     if(move_uploaded_file($temp_file, "$uploads_dir/$name")){
     //Fire Insert Query For Insert image name in your database
     }
     else
     {  
      echo "Error !! , Your image not uploaded.";
     }
    }
   ?>
```